# Веб-приложение: наполнение пространства

Tags: jquery, javascript, actionscript

Хочу написать веб-приложение, в котором можно будет перетаскивать блоки в некое поле. 
В базе данных есть некоторые позиции (товары), у них есть высота, ширина, длина. Выбирая эти объекты, их можно разместить в некой области.

Какие есть модули и плагины, которые упростят мне работу?

Или это только на флэш можно реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант можно использовать jQuery UI

[Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/), [Droppable](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/)

Comment: Здорово. А 3d решений нет?

Comment: какой жесткий тетрис планируется, однако... :)

Comment: 3d решений не встречал )